# Boost spirit changing variable value in semantic action

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

I want to change a local variable value in semantic action, like following:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
using boost::phoenix::ref;
using boost::phoenix::bind;

void dummy(const std::vector<char>& v, int& var)
{
    var = 7;
}

template <typename Iterator>
struct x_grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type>
{
public:
    x_grammar() : x_grammar::base_type(start_rule, "x_grammar")
    {
        using namespace qi;
        int local_var = 0;
        start_rule = (+(char_ - ";"))[bind(dummy, _1, ref(local_var))];
        //repeat(ref(local_var))[some_rule];
    }
private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> start_rule;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iter;
    std::string storage("string;aaa");
    iter it_begin(storage.begin());
    iter it_end(storage.end());
    std::string read_data;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
    x_grammar<iter> g;
    try {
        bool r = qi::phrase_parse(it_begin, it_end, g, space, read_data);
        std::cout << "Pass!\n";
    } catch (const qi::expectation_failure<iter>& x) {
        std::cout << "Error!\n";
    }
}
```

I am getting some annoying compile errors using GCC 4.6.1 with boost 1.55.

Comment: The local variable only "lives" until the end of the constructor. If you want to do something similar to that, you'll need to make the variable a member of the grammar (or maybe pass it as a parameter to the constructor). Also using `boost::phoenix::bind` (or `ref`) without namespace qualification with a c++11 compiler presents ADL problems when used with parameters of a class in namespace std (`std::vector` in this case). You should use something like `namespace phx=boost::phoenix;... phx::bind(dummy,_1,phx::ref(local_var));`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't help but note that if compiler errors annoy you, then perhaps you should write valid code :/

---

### Instructive Hat On...

While that's of course a flippant remark, it's also somewhat enlightening.

I've told you **twice** now that the whole idea of using constructor local variables in your grammar is *fundamentally broken*:

- [Boost spirit semantic action not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757504/boost-spirit-semantic-action-not-invoked)
- [Boost spirit using local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763233/boost-spirit-using-local-variables)

What you want is

- inherited attributes
- qi::locals
- maayyyyybe, maaaayyybe grammar member variables; with the caveat that they make your rules non-re-entrant.

The important thing here to really get inside your head is

> Boost Spirit generates parser from **expression templates**. Expression templates are 90% static information (type only), and get "compiled" (`.compile()`) into "invokable" (`.parse()`) form.
>
> Most importantly, while you *can* write control flow in your semantic actions, none of this actually executed at the definition site. It's "compiled" into a *lazy actor* that can later be invoked.
>
> The generated parse will conditionally invoke the lazy actor when the corresponding parse expression matches

---

### Constructive Hat On...

It looks like you just want to transform attributes using a function.

Here's what you can do:

1. transform as part of the semantic action, placing the result into the regular attribute (maintaining 'functional' semantics for parser composition):

   ```
   qi::rule<Iterator, exposed(), Skipper> myrule;
   myrule = int_ [ _val = phx::bind(custom_xform, _1) ];
   ```

   Where `custom_xform` is any old-school calleable (including polymorphic ones):

   ```
   exposed custom_xform(int i) { return make_new_exposed(i); } 
   // or
   struct custom_xfrom_t {

     template <typename> struct result { typedef exposed type; };

     template <typename Int>
       exposed operator()(Int i) const {
           return make_new_exposed(i);
       }
   };
   static const custom_xform_t custom_xform;
   ```
2. You can add some syntactic sugar **<sup>[1]</sup>**

   ```
   qi::rule<Iterator, exposed(), Skipper> myrule;
   myrule = int_ [ _val = custom_xform(_1) ];
   ```

   This requires `custom_xform` is defined as a lazy actor:

   ```
   phx::function<custom_xform_t> custom_xform; // `custom_xform_t` again the (polymorphic) functor
   ```

   > *You may note this wouldn't work for a regular function. You could wrap it in a calleable object, or use the `BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION` macro to do just that for you*
3. If you have some more involved transformations that you want to apply more often, consider using the Spirit Customization Points:

   - [Customization of Spirit's Attribute Handling](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize.html), specifically:

     - [Transform an Attribute to a Different Type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/transform.html)
     - [Store a Parsed Attribute Value](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/assign_to.html)

   These work most smoothly if you choose specific types for your attributes (e.g. `Ast::Multiplicity` or `Ast::VelocityRanking`, instead of `int` or `double`

---

**<sup>[1]</sup>** using BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

Comment: Will add some (even more) constructive comments in a minute.

Comment: Okay, more constructive content added as well. I'm sure you will be able to fix the [hidden **XY Problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with this. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I guess you are right, I did not understand some fundamentals of boost spirit. I just did not have enough time to do it.

Comment: To the downvoter: it says a lot about you if you can't easily observe that the answer is _dominated_ by constructivism and a boatload of on-topic information, _yet_ you find it important to downvote an answer 2 years late.

Answer (score 2):

The code [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef52a6f945312ecf) with C++03.  However, when using GCC 4.6's C++11 support, the code [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cd34d69365d48ac).  Here are the relevant excerpts from the error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/support/action_dispatch.hpp: In static
    member function 'static void boost::spirit::traits::action_dispatch<
    Component>::caller(F&&, A&& ...) [with F =
    const std::_Bind<with Boost.Phoenix actors>]'

...

main.cpp:25:9: instantiated from 'x_grammar<Iterator>::x_grammar() [...]

/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/support/action_dispatch.hpp:142:13: error:
    no matching function for call to 'boost::spirit::traits::
    action_dispatch<...>::do_call(const std::_Bind<with Boost.Phoenix actors>)'
```

Despite the `using boost::phoenix::bind` directive, the unqualified call to `bind()` is resolving to `std::bind()` rather than [`boost::phoenix::bind()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/bind/binding_functions.html), but the arguments are resolving to Boost.Phoenix actors.  The Boost.Spirit [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html#spirit.qi.tutorials.semantic_actions.phoenix) specifically warns about not mixing placeholders from different libraries:

> You have to make sure not to mix placeholders with a library they don't belong to and not to use different libraries while writing a semantic action.

Hence, the compilation problem can be resolved by being explicit when defining the semantic action.  Use either:

```cpp
std::bind(dummy, std::placeholders::_1, std::ref(local_var))
```

or:

```cpp
boost::phoenix::bind(dummy, _1, ref(local_var))
```

While that resolves the compiler error, it is worth noting that the `ref(local_var)` object will maintain a dangling reference, as its lifetime extends beyond that of `local_var`.  Here is a working [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/546230d9073791d6) where `local_var`'s lifetime is extend to beyond the scope of the constructor by making it static.